# Why is it giving me the 'Access to path denied' error when i try to run my c# code in sublime?

Tags: c#, path, sublimetext3

I am trying to run my c# code using ScriptCS in Sublime. I have added ScriptCS(and sublime just in case, since i don't really understand path that well) to `PATH`. It gives me this error

```
Copying directory 'packages' to 'scriptcs_packages'...

Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'scriptcs_packages' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at ScriptCs.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(String source, String dest, Boolean overwrite)
   at ScriptCs.FileSystemMigrator.Migrate()
   at ScriptCs.Command.CommandFactory.CreateCommand(Config config, String[] scriptArgs)
   at ScriptCs.Application.Run(Config config, String[] scriptArgs)
   at ScriptCs.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

and if it helps, here is what the file contains. It most probably doesn't contain anything that contributes to the issue i'm facing, but here it is anyway.

```cs
    using System;
    using static System.Console;
    
    namespace main { 
    
        class menu {
    
    
        }
    
        class game { 
    
            public void Start() {
                WriteLine("Hello World");
    
                ReadKey(true);
            }
    
        }
    
        class Program { 
    
            static void Main(string args) {
                game myGame = new game();
                myGame.Start();
    
            }
    
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to run sublime as administrator ?

Comment: @gokhancevik When I did that, the error became 'you cannot declare namespace in script code' so when i removed the namespace, it didnt output anything